# Python Pandas is it possible to find the max value in a generated series without having to store the series into memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the maximum value of a calculation on a column in a dataframe.  To do this I'm creating the calculation column and then calling `max()` on it.

`df['two'] = df['one']/df['one'].index
maximum = df['two'].max()`

This is a slow operation and I'm wondering if its possible to optimize it by avoiding the memory use for the calculation column and just calculate the column on the fly while keeping track of its maximum value.  I can do this in vanilla python but I want the efficiency of pandas.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can try to cheat, but we need to know the exact formula/algorithm.

In your example it can be done without storing the column:

```
maximum = (df.a/df.index).max()
```

if it's more complex calculation you can use `.assign()` method:

```
maximum = df.assign(two=df.a/df.index)['two'].max()
```

Test:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
    a  b  c
0   0  9  3
1   7  6  5
2   4  5  8
3   0  4  3
4   7  4  5
5   0  9  9
6   7  5  2
7   4  4  4
8   1  3  3
9   3  1  3
10  6  6  1
11  8  4  0
12  6  2  9
13  4  1  0
14  8  5  9

In [20]: df.assign(two=df.a/df.index)['two'].max()
Out[20]: 7.0

In [21]: (df.a/df.index).max()
Out[21]: 7.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the most efficient!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you sacrifice efficiency in memory for efficiency in processing.

You could just write a loop.

```
maximum = np.nan
for i in range(len(df.a)):
    if pd.isnull(maximum):
        maximum = df.a[i] / df.index[i]
    else:
        maximum = max(maximum, df.a[i] / df.index[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be very memory efficient.  It uses `iterrows` and a generator for `max`.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))

df
Out[107]: 
          a         b         c
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

>>> max(row.a / idx for  idx, row in df.iterrows() if idx)
2.2408931992014578
```

The `if idx` is to remove instances where the denominator is zero or None.